# When are questions deletable and when are they not deletable?

Tags: discussion

I tried to delete a question after getting a lot of negative feedback and getting the impression that most responders and commenters didn't really know the topic I was inquiring about. I got "You can't delete this question because others put effort into answering it" message.

But around the same time, another question that I put some effort into answering was deleted, and this despite the fact that I had already posted my answer.

So why the double standard?

Comment: [Help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) actually has already explained this in detail...

Answer (score 2):

As [Andrew T.](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28728/andrew-t) mentioned in comments, the [Help Section](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) explains this already. Quoting from it:

> Users can delete their own questions if the question:
>
> - has zero answers
> - has only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes
> - has no bounties that were awarded to any answer that isn't already deleted

So, without knowing what question(s) you refer to (if you can try including the links for better answer), most likely that question you wrote and tried to delete already had more than one answer, thus preventing you from deleting it.

If you *really* want to delete it, then only a Mod can do it, but you will have to ask one for such.

Now, regarding the question you answered but got deleted, there is no "double standard" here. Most likely (again, can't know for sure if you don't say what Q it is), the question was closed by the Community, or well some mod. Again, from the help section:

> Questions can also be deleted by the community. Moderators can delete any question, and users with sufficient reputation can cast delete votes on closed questions. It takes 3 votes, minimum, to delete a closed question. However, the number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on the question and all its answers. Questions that have been closed within the past 48 hours cannot be deleted, so as to allow for editing and possible reopening.